# Compute $f^{(2001)}(0)$ where $f(x) = e^{-x}\sin(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

**The question:** Let $f(x) = e^{-x}\sin(x)$. Calculate $f^{(2001)}(0)$.

Note that in the question, $f^{(n)}(x)$. means the $n$-th derivative of $f$.

I calculated the first six derivatives on zero and got:

$f^{(0)}(0) = 0$.

$f^{(1)}(0) = 1$.

$f^{(2)}(0) = -2$.

$f^{(3)}(0) = 2$.

$f^{(4)}(0) = 0$.

$f^{(5)}(0) = -4$.

$f^{(6)}(0) = 8$.

So, the pattern isn't pretty clear.
Also, I thought that if $n$ is even, then:

$f^{(n)}(x) = -e^{-x}\cos(x) - f(x) + f^{(1)}(x) - f^{(2)}(x) + ... + f^{(n-3)}(x) - f^{(n-2)}(x) - f^{(n-1)}(x)$.

and $f^{(n - 1)}(x) = e^{-x}\cos(x) + f(x) - f^{(1)}(x) + f^{(2)}(x) + ... + f^{(n-4)}(x) - f^{(n-3)}(x) - f^{(n-2)}(x)$.

So by substituting $f^{(n - 1)}(x)$ in the first equation, we get:

$f^{(n)}(x) = -2(e^{-x}\cos(x) + f(x) - f^{(1)}(x) + f^{(2)}(x) + ... + f^{(n-4)}(x) - f^{(n-3)}(x))$

I tried to the same thing with $n$ being odd and tried to perform an induction to get a formula for the value of $f^{(n)}(x)$ but couldn't find a way to do so. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know Euler's formula relating sine, cosine, and exponential?

Comment: Hint: If $f(x)=e^{-x}\sin x$ then $f''(x)=-2e^{-x}\cos x$. If $g(x)=e^{-x}\cos x$ then $g''(x)=2e^{-x}\sin x$.

Comment: Ow sure, i forgot the we get back to the function with double derivation (as used to integrate by parts). Thanks, now i solved it

Comment: calculate f'(x),f''(x),f''(x),f''''(x), ... and you will see a pattern

Comment: @miracle173 The OP went up to the 6th derivative and he found no pattern. And even if some pattern would emerge,  how certain can you be that it is correct?

Comment: @imranfat the OP calculated $f^{(k)}(0)$ and not $f^{(k)}(x)$. I am pretty sure he will recognize the pattern. It is easy to proof the pattern. Try it out and you will see!

Comment: Even without complex numbers, define $C:=e^{-x}\cos x,\,S:=e^{-x}\sin x$ so $C^\prime=-C-S,\,S^\prime:=C-S$ and $C^{\prime\prime}=2S,\,S^{\prime\prime}=-2C$. Hence $S^{(4)}=-2C^{\prime\prime}=-4S$, and $S^{(2001)}=(-4)^{500}S^\prime=2^{1000}e^{-x}(\cos x-\sin x)$.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, by Euler's formula we have that

$$f(x) = \Im \left(e^{-x+ix}\right) \implies f^n(0)=\Im \left((-1+i)^n\right)$$

then we can use that

- $\arg (z^n)=n\arg(z)$
- $|z^n|=|z|^n$